# locally noetherian scheme with integral local rings is disjoint union of integral schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, noetherian

I have read in some places that a if you have a locally noetherian <s>connected</s> scheme $X$ such that $\forall x \in X$, $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$ is a integral domain, then $X$ is the disjoint union of integral schemes. However I haven't been able to find a proof. Could anybody give a proof or a reference to one?

Comment: Hint: what does the local ring of a point on two irreducible components look like? Is it a domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A connected scheme cannot be the disjoint union of integral schemes. So you misread. What is true is that a *locally Noetherian scheme $X$ is integral if and only if $X$ is connected and all its stalks $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are integral domains*.

Here is a sketch of the main part of the argument, you could google the details. For any scheme $X$ and $x\in X$, the irreducible components of $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ are in bijective correspondence with the irreducible components of $X$ passing through $x$. In our case $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is an integral domain, so $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ is irreducible and therefore every point $x$ has a unique irreducible component passing through it. So the irreducible components of $X$ are mutually disjoint. In a locally Noetherian topological space, this is equivalent to saying that the irreducible components of $X$ are the same as its connected components. But since $X$ is connected, there is only one such component.

**Caution:** The Noetherian assumption is important. There exists a [nonintegral connected scheme whose local rings are domains](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0568)